# Can someone help vertex shader error in pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, pyglet, vertex-shader

I have singled out this code in causing an error

```
    self.vertex_shader_source = """
    #version 130
    in layout (location = 0) vec3 position;
    in layout (location = 1) vec3 color;
            
    out vec3 newColor;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
        newColor = color;
    }
    """
    
    self.fragment_shader_source = """
    #version 130
    in vec3 newColor;
    
    out vec4 outColor;
    void main()
    {
        outColor = vec4(newColor, 1.0f);
    }
    """
```

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/awesomenoob/Coding/Python/Rendering/Opengl-tri.py", line 23, in <module>
window = MyWindow(1280, 720, "yoot", resizable=True)
File "/home/awesomenoob/Coding/Python/Rendering/Opengl-tri.py", line 10, in __init__
self.triangle = Triangle()
File "/home/awesomenoob/Coding/Python/Rendering/Triangle.py", line 35, in __init__
shader = 
OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(self.vertex_shader_source, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
File "/home/awesomenoob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 241, in compileShader
shaderType,
OpenGL.GL.shaders.ShaderCompilationError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b"0:3(12): error: 
syntax error, unexpected \'(\', expecting \'{\'\\n"', [b'\n        #version 130\n        in 
layout (location = 0) vec3 position;\n        in layout (location = 1) vec3 color;\n                
\n        out vec3 newColor;\n        void main()\n        {\n            gl_Position = 
vec4(position, 1.0f);\n            newColor = color;\n        }\n        '], 35633)
```

if you could help me understand what i did wrong that would be a huge help. I am just trying to learn pyglet/opengl in python

Comment: The syntax guide says it needs to be `layout (location  = 0) in vec3 position;`.

Comment: @TimRoberts No. Both is fine, from version 3.30 upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex shader attribute location [Layout qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) are supported since GLSL Version 3.30. Compare [OpenGL Shading Language 1.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) and [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf). If possible, use GLSL 3.00.

Alternatively remove the layout qualifiers:

```c
#version 130
in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;
        
out vec3 newColor;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    newColor = color;
}
```

Set the attribute locations with [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBindAttribLocation.html) before the program is linked or get the attribute locations with [`glGetAttribLocation`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetAttribLocation.html) after the program is linked.

e.g.:

```py
shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(...)
position_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, b'position')
color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, b'color')
```

Comment: Thx so much. tho i didn't need glBind or glGet.

Comment: @AwesomeNoob999 No. You need `glBindAttribLocation` or `glGetAttribLocation`. Very  likely the attribute indices are 0 and 1. However, there is no guarantee that it will. Your program may work on your system, but it may fail on another system.

Comment: it shows this error  "glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position")
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type "

Comment: pops up same error,if it changes anything, my opengl version is 3.0

Comment: question name can't get attribute location pyglet